# I am getting error in compililing the trigger in oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers

Need help on this trigger which updating a record when user perform update on particular column.
Ex. here I have created a table orders as below.

```
CREATE TABLE orders
   ( order_id number(5),
     quantity number(4),
     status_c varchar2(15), 
     delete_date date,
     deleted_by_id varchar2(10));
```

I have inserted 2 records in it as below.

```
insert into orders values (1,25,'FAILED',null,null);
insert into orders values (1,50,'QUEUED',null,null);

select * from orders;
```

ORDER_ID   QUANTITY STATUS_C        DELETE_DA DELETED_BY

---

```
     1         25 FAILED
     1         50 QUEUED
```

Now we can see the values for column STATUS_C as 'FAILED' and 'QUEUED'

So I whenever new user updates this table - orders , and make the status as 'DELETED' for status_c, then I need to capture his details such person_id and sysdate, So I have written a below trigger on that table - Orders

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER orders_before_update
  BEFORE UPDATE
     ON orders
    FOR EACH ROW

  DECLARE
     v_username varchar2(10);

  BEGIN

   If UPDATING then

        if upper(:new.status_c) = 'DELETED' then

       -- Find username of person performing UPDATE on the table
       SELECT user INTO v_username
       FROM dual;

       -- Update delete_date field to current system date
       :new.delete_date := sysdate;

       -- Update deleted_by_id field to the username of the person performing the UPDATE
       :new.deleted_by_id := v_username   

    end if;

    end if;
   END;
   /
```

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

I got error while compile.

I tried to udpate the table to see its impact,

```
    update orders set status_c = 'DELETED' where order_id = 1;
    update orders set status_c = 'DELETED' where order_id = 1
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04098: trigger 'DISDBA.ORDERS_BEFORE_UPDATE' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

I need help what is the issue in trigger, and why it is not compiling.

When I checked the error using below query. it says.

```
 `select * from user_errors where type = 'TRIGGER' and name` ='ORDERS_BEFORE_UPDATE';

NAME                           TYPE           SEQUENCE       LINE   POSITION
------------------------------ ------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
TEXT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORDERS_BEFORE_UPDATE           TRIGGER               1         20          5
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in mod not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like
   between is null is not || is dangling
The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.
```

Need help on this.

Comment: missing semicolon `:new.deleted_by_id := v_username` ?

Answer (score 0):

Missing semi-colon on this line:

```
       :new.deleted_by_id := v_username
```